# TeamCity global version per PROJECT (not configuration)

Tags: teamcity

The Build number property in TeamCity is unique for each build configuration.

I'd like to have a single counter that will be used across all different build configurations (to count how many times in total i've built the product).

1. Does this make sense? (it does to me).
2. How can this be done, if the property is stored per configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Makes perfect sense.
2. I think the [Autoincrementer](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/Autoincrementer) plugin is what you're looking for.

It lets you have a single builder counter across any number of build configurations. We use it so nightly build numbers are shared with checkin-builds.

Comment: awesome thanks ! i had totally overlooked plugins to extend it :)